# Jsp get and parse url to view JAVA

Tags: java, jsp

I have passed this url parameter.

```
?previous=[{user_id=3,%20email=ivanov@test.eu,%20budget_limit=23.00,%20budget_remain=9.87,%20status=1,%20first_name=Test,%20last_name=Test,%20middle_name=Test,%20egn=553745347,%20firm=,%20mol=,%20phone=000000000,%20address=Test,%20shipping_address=null,%20zdds=true,%20pay_type=0,%20bulstat=}]
```

I am trying to show this in jsp page. I have got the parameters and print the to console like this.

```
<%
        String[] previous = request.getParameterValues("previous");

        for (int i = 0; i < previous.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(previous[i]);
        }
%>
```

But i do not know how to pass them to the view page ?

Comment: You can use JSTL.

Comment: example please :)

Comment: Put out.println(previous[i]); instead of System.out.println(previous[i]);

Comment: this will directly write the value on the screen.

Comment: @happy OK! That`s cool but how to access and format it ?

Comment: @nnenov I have added explanation. If you need code that I can provide you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your URL first otherwise you will end up writing parsing logic.

**Sample Request :** http://localhost:8080/hello?user_id=3&email=ivanov@test.eu&budget_limit=23.00

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<body>
    <c:forEach var="par" items="${paramValues}">
        ${par.key} = ${par.value[0]};
    </c:forEach>
</body>
```

**Output :** This will be visible on browser.

```
user_id = 3; budget_limit = 23.00; email = ivanov@test.eu;
```

Comment: Data is like this in browser. How to add it to a html table ?
[{user_id = 3, budget_limit = 23.00, email = ivanov@test.eu, bulstat=}];